# Passing a PHP Class object to Javascript and accessing its properties in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having trouble accessing the properties of an `object` within a Javascript function I created. The object is originally a PHP `object` which I encoded as `JSON` using `json_encode()`

I have 1 PHP file and 1 **external** JS file.

In my PHP file, I have the ff:

```
<?php
    $announcementDaoImpl = new AnnouncementDaoImpl($pdo);
    $announcementList = $announcementDaoImpl->getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent();
    foreach($announcementList as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value->getId(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->getTitle(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->getDateAdded(); ?></td>
        <?php echo json_encode($value); ?> 
        <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="showEditModal('modalBox',<?php echo json_encode($value); ?>)">Edit</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am able to get and display the values by using the `get()` methods on the `<td>`'s. However, when I encode it to `JSON` via `json_encode($value)`, I get nothing.

Line

```
<?php echo json_encode($value); ?>
```

`echoe`s `{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}` which seems to be empty objects.

My goals are to be able to pass the `$value` `php` object to the javascript method `showEditModal()` then access the object's properties within the method block. Something like, `object.propertyname`

Below is the javascript method `showEditModal()` implementation.

```
function showEditModal(modalDivId,object){
    alert(object.title); //returns undefined

    var modalBox = document.getElementById(modalDivId);
    var modalContentValues = document.getElementById("modalContentValues");
    modalBox.style.display = "block";
    var node = document.createElement("p");
    var text = document.createTextNode(object); //shows [object Object]
    node.style.display = "inline";
    node.appendChild(text);
    modalContentValues.appendChild(node);
}
```

--- EDIT ---

Here's the class definition.

```
class Announcement {
    private $id;
    private $title;
    private $content;
    private $dateAdded;


    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function getDateAdded()
    {
        return $this->dateAdded;
    }

    public function setDateAdded($dateAdded)
    {
        $this->dateAdded = $dateAdded;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}
```

-- end of edit --

This is what displays on my browser.

[image]

I've added some comments to the javascript method for additional details.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface to define what properties you want to make visible when you serialise an object; e.g:

```
<?php 

class User implements \JsonSerializable
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
        ];
    }
}

echo json_encode(new User('Bob')); // {"name":"Bob"}
```

This is an idiomatic way to handle object serialisation in PHP in a transparent and implicit manner, and it allows you to define a preferred shape/format for the json respresentation of your object and encapsulate it within its class definition.

It's quite handy when serialising nested object structures, for example, when you were using value objects - here's a (contrived) example:

```
class Latitude implements \JsonSerializable
{
    private $degree;

    public function __construct(float $degree)
    {
        // validation etc.
        $this->degree = $degree;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize(): float
    {
        return $this->degree;
    }
}

class Longitude implements \JsonSerializable
{
    private $degree;

    public function __construct(float $degree)
    {
        // validation etc.
        $this->degree = $degree;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize(): float
    {
        return $this->degree;
    }
}

class Coordinate implements \JsonSerializable
{
    public function __construct(Latitude $latitude, Longitude $longitude)
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize(): array
    {
        return [
          'latlng' => [$this->latitude, $this->longitude],
        ];
    }
}

$coordinate = new Coordinate(new Latitude(0), new Longitude(0));

echo json_encode($coordinate); // {"latlng":[0,0]}
```

Example: https://repl.it/repls/RelievedLightcyanFolders

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After trying your suggestion, I was able to echo the encoded values. However, my Javascript method won't even display an `alert()` when `showEditModal()` is called. 

I get the ff. when I `echo json_encode(new Announcement());`

`{"id":2,"title":"Announcement 1","content":"Announcement 1 Content","dateAdded":"2018-04-24 14:44:27"} {"id":1,"title":"Test Announcement Title","content":"Test Announcement Content","dateAdded":"2018-04-22 16:12:06"}`

Comment: Do you have any ideas why the js method `showEditModal()` won't execute now?

Comment: Firstly, I'd check if there is an error in your browser's web developer toolbar.

Comment: It looks like you want to pass a JS object literal into `showEditModal` but it looks like you are passing in the jsonified string directly. If so, you'll have to use `JSON.parse()` to convert the string into a JS object. and since you are dealing with a string you may have to quote the PHP code as well; e.g: `showEditModal('foo JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($foo)'));`. Again, check for errors in your browser's web console.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried it but having trouble, I guess with escaping quotes or maybe I'm not doing it right.

`<a href='#' onclick='showEditModal(&apos;modalBox&apos;, &apos;JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($value)?>);&apos; )' >
                                    Edit
                                </a>`

Comment: I get a String value of `JSON.parse({"id":2,"title":"Announcement 1","content":"Announcement 1 Content","dateAdded":"2018-04-24 14:44:27"});` when I put it on a `<p>`

Comment: Not sure why you are using `&apos;` and you should not quote `JSON.parse` in any case. I realised my last comment had a typo. I meant to write: `showEditModal('modalBox', JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($value)'));`.

Comment: Actually, sorry - just reading your code again. Does this work? `showEditModal('modalBox', <?php echo json_encode($value) ?>)` - it should do, without quotes or JSON.parse.

Comment: I'm having problems escaping the quotes I think. I can't figure out which part. I tried your suggestion `<a href='#' onclick='showEditModal('modalBox', JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($value)?>')); ' >` but inspector says `unexpected end of input`

Comment: Try this: `<a href="#" onclick="showEditModal('modalBox', <?php echo json_encode($value) ?>);">`. Note that I am: a. using double quotes in the HTML markup b. single quotes in JS c. not using `JSON.parse()` d. not quoting the PHP at all (I was mistaken in my reading of your code earlier)

Comment: Thanks again. I don't know why it won't work. I tried your suggestion. When I went to check the source, I get this. `<a href="#" onclick="showEditModal('modalBox' , {"id":2,"title":"Announcement 1","content":"Announcement 1 Content","dateAdded":"2018-04-24 14:44:27"});">Edit</a>` I'm gonna try to get around and fix this but if you find anything that might be causing it, please let me know. I'll stop the thread for now. Hope this isn't much of a trouble.

Comment: I think I know - things can be messy when mixing multiple languages, and HTML! Since JSON strings (keys and values) are double-quoted - e.g: `{"name": "jordan"}` - there is probably a problem with unbalanced quotes because you're doing all of this inside an `onclick` attribute. Try updating the `onclick` attribute with: `onclick='showEditModal("modalBox", <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>)'`. Pay careful attention to the use of single or double quotes. The string echoed from `json_decode` should be interpreted as a JS object - check the source to see its keys and values are double-quoted.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I'll keep that in mind. I was able to fix it by using the `htmlentities()` `<a href="#" onclick="showEditModal('modalBox',<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($value)); ?>)">Edit</a>` Could you suggest how I can avoid mixing the languages?

Answer (score 1):

I'd venture this is because `json_encode()` scans the public properties of the object and puts those into the results, but in your code you always use getter functions. It's hard to tell without knowing the class definition of the objects you have in `$announcementList`. Try this:

```
<?php echo json_encode([
    'id' => $value->getId(),
    'title' => $value->getTitle(),
    'dateAdded' => $value->getDateAdded(),
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen in your php code, you access the objects attributes via methods. That sounds like the attributes are private. That's why when you are trying to encode the object the result is an empty object.

What you could do:

```
class MyObject
{
    private $attribute1;
    private $attribute2;

    public function getAttribute1()
    {
        return $this->attribute1;
    }

    public function getAttribute2()
    {
        return $this->attribute2;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'attribute1' => $this->attribute1,
            'attribute2' => $this->attribute2,
        ];
    }

    public function toJson()
    {
        return json_encode($this->toArray());
    }
}
```

Now in the php file you can use it like:

```
<?php
    $announcementDaoImpl = new AnnouncementDaoImpl($pdo);
    $announcementList = $announcementDaoImpl->getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent();
    foreach($announcementList as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value->getAttribute1(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->getAttribute2(); ?></td>
        <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="showEditModal('modalBox',<?php echo $value->toJson() ?>)">Edit</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be elegantly demonstrated with this simple code:

```
class Foo {
    private $a = 0;
    protected $b = 1;
    public $c = 2;
}
echo json_encode(new Foo);
// Outputs {"c":2}
```

Given a standard object, `json_encode` will only serialize the *public* properties of the object. If the object you are trying to serialize makes use of private or protected properties, those will not be visible to the JSON encoder; if that's *all* the object has, you'll get an empty JSON object, like in your case.

If you can alter the class in question, you can implement [the  `JsonSerializable` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) to customise the properties to be serialized. If you can't, you will need to build your own representation to pass to JavaScript using the public getter methods, e.g.

```
echo json_encode([
      'id' => $value->getId(),
      'title' => $value->getTitle(),
      'dateAdded' => $value->getDateAdded()
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to encode an object that contains *public methods*, but no *public properties*. `json_encode` will encode only the *public properties*.

You can just create an object with real *public properties* and then serialize it:

```
<?php
    $announcementDaoImpl = new AnnouncementDaoImpl($pdo);
    $announcementList = $announcementDaoImpl->getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent();
    foreach($announcementList as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value->getId(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->getTitle(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->getDateAdded(); ?></td>
        <?php 
             $obj = new stdClass(); 
             $obj->Id = $value->getId();
             $obj->Title= $value->getTitle();
             $obj->DateAdded= $value->getDateAdded();
             var_dump($value);  // just for debugging
             var_dump($obj);    // just for debugging
             echo json_encode($obj); 
        ?> 
        <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="showEditModal('modalBox',<?php echo json_encode($obj); ?>)">Edit</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

do like like

```
<a href="#" onclick="showEditModal('modalBox','<?php echo json_encode($value); ?>')">Edit</a>
```

and inside your function

```
    function showEditModal(modalDivId,object){
        object = JSON.parse(object) // convert json string to json object
        alert(object.title); //returns undefined

        var modalBox = document.getElementById(modalDivId);
        var modalContentValues = document.getElementById("modalContentValues");
        modalBox.style.display = "block";
        var node = document.createElement("p");
        var text = document.createTextNode(object); //shows [object Object]
        node.style.display = "inline";
        node.appendChild(text);
        modalContentValues.appendChild(node);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I still get the same result. `undefined` on `alert()` and `[object Object]` on `createTextNode(object)`

Comment: did you try  `alert(object[0].title);`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to encode an object that contains *public methods*, but no public properties. `json_encode` will encode only the `public properties`.

A different, elegant and simple approach is using [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) to create a new object with *public properties* 'reflecting' your original object *private* ones:

```
   <?php
   $announcementDaoImpl = new AnnouncementDaoImpl($pdo);
   $announcementList = $announcementDaoImpl->getAllAnnouncementByMostRecent(); 
   foreach($announcementList as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value->getId(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->getTitle(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->getDateAdded(); ?></td>
        <?php
             // gets all PRIVATE properties of $value and stores them to $obj 
             $reflect = new ReflectionClass($value);
             $obj = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE);
             
             echo json_encode($obj); 
        ?> 
        <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="showEditModal('modalBox',<?php echo json_encode($obj); ?>)">Edit</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```